# Button added with Jquery .html() function doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I have a function that shows a div called "window". I want to introduce 2 buttons inside this window when the function is executed, so I use .html():

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#show").click(function() {
        $(".window").fadeIn();
        $(".window").html("<button id='ok'>ok</button><button id='cancel'>Cancel</button>");
        $("#ok").click(function() {

            //my function...

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The problem is that although the button "ok" and the button "cancel" is displayed inside the div "window",
only the button "ok" works. The button "cancel" doesn't work when is clicked! What is wrong?

Cancel function:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cancel").click(function(){
        $(".window").fadeOut("fast");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The event handler for `#cancel` is initialized before the element is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#show").click(function(){
    $(".window").fadeIn();
    $(".window").html("<button id='ok'>ok</button><button id='cancel'>Cancel</button>");

    $("#ok").click(function(){

    });

    $("#cancel").click(function(){
        $(".window").fadeOut();
    });
});
});
```

EDIT: (correct jsfiddle link)
An example: http://jsfiddle.net/7TCcf/
Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recent-ish jQuery, try using `.on(e, selector, fn)` instead of the click method. Using .on will delegate events so you can bind something to a parent selector and the handler will function even if the selector you want isn't currently in the DOM.

You could take the `$('#ok')` completely out of the handler and do the following:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#show").click(function() {
        $(".window").fadeIn();
        $(".window").html("<button id='ok'>ok</button><button id='cancel'>Cancel</button>");
    });
});

$("[parent of ok]").on('click', '#ok', function() {
    //my function...
});
</script>
```

See more here: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Answer (score 0):

This will work (If there is no other errors in your script):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".window").on('click', 'button#ok', function(e){
        // ...
    })
    .on('click', 'button#cancel', function(e){
        // ...
    });

    $("#show").click(function() {
        $(".window").fadeIn();
    });
});
```